# get html element by id vb.net

Tags: html, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to change the background color of a div when clicked. The div is inside a link button which is the sender in this function:

```
Public Sub ClickDiv(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim lnkbtn As LinkButton = TryCast(sender, LinkButton)
End sub
```

How can i get the div inside of this link button (the div has command argument as id). What I've tried so far (i am getting div=Nothing):

```
Dim div As HtmlControl = TryCast(lnkbtn.FindControl(lnkbtn.CommandArgument), HtmlControl)
```

or

```
Dim div As HtmlControl = TryCast(Page.FindControl(lnkbtn.CommandArgument), HtmlControl)
```

HTML in source code:

```
    <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl21','')" style="text-decoration:none;">
         <div id="x11" class="col-md-1" runat="server">11</div>
    </a>
```

Creation of Link button and div:

```
Dim div As HtmlGenericControl = New HtmlGenericControl()
div.Attributes.Add("id", "y" & i)
div.Attributes.Add("class", "col-md-2")
div.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")

Dim lnkbtn As LinkButton = New LinkButton
AddHandler lnkbtn.Click, AddressOf Me.ClickDiv
lnkbtn.CommandArgument = "y" & i
lnkbtn.Controls.Add(div)
divrepeater.Controls.Add(lnkbtn)
```

Comment: can you post your code for the link button?

Comment: I've edited my post @CodingDuchess

Comment: You should try first to find the repeater, and then use repeater.FindControl to find your linkbutton

Comment: The divrepeater is not a repeater, it is the main div in which i am adding dynamically link buttons and divs. In my function i was able to get the link button but what I want is the div inside it